# on modifying the shape of numpy array resulting from input image

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to customize an existing code to suit my own need. Originally, the code use `imgs = np.ndarray((total, 1, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)` to store a list of image files in an numpy array format. Iterating the folder, each image file is read as follows `img = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(train_data_path, image_name))` It works just fine.
The code is as follows:

```
 image_rows = 420
 image_cols = 580
 imgs = np.ndarray((total, 1, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
 i=0
 for image_name in images:
     img = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(train_data_path, image_name))
     img = np.array([img])
     imgs[i]=img
     i+=1
```

In order to suit my own need, I tend to have image file array with the shape `[total, image_rows,image_cols,1]`. In other words, I modified it as `imgs = np.ndarray((total,image_rows, image_cols,1), dtype=np.uint8)`  However, running the code causes the following error

```
 imgs[i] = img
 ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,420,580) into shape         
(420,580,1)
```

Are there any way to change the shape of `img`, which originally has shape of `[1,420,580]` after reading from file. How can I change it to `[420,580,1]` without affecting the corresponding pixel values in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transpose the dimensions. It can be done using the transpose method:

```
img = img.transpose(1,2,0)
```

(for your  case)

Comment: Thanks, will img.reshape work. I also tried reshape. Looks like the code can compile. My only concern for using reshape is that how can I ensure the pixels in [1,420,580] can exactly match the pixels [420,580,1].